# Why is border-radius property giving me different result after switching it off and on again?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am using primeng's radio button and white circle inside has a border radius of 50%.

However, at first, it is "glitchy" and not 50% (it has a kind of sharp edge at the right bottom corner).

Before switching the `border-radius` property in Developer Tools:

[image]

After I switch the `border-radius` property off and back on, it fixes itself for some reason:

[image]

Comment: Probably a defect in the user agent. Since "developer tools" isn't even part of any Web standard, whatever effect it may have on what is rendered in the viewport, cannot possibly have anything to do with implementation of any Web standard. In short, it's a bug in the user agent. Why do you worry about it so much? Do you plan on instructing your users to use Developer Tools?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code you are using to perform this task as text. You may wish to use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar) to do so.

Comment: my point is that, when I load the page, it's not round. it becomes round only after i turn the border radius off from devTools and then turn it on again.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Our motto here is “proper example, or it didn’t happen.” We can’t _debug_ anything, by just being shown some screenshots of the rendered result.

Comment: Try increasing size by 1px. It's just browser that renders element incorrectly. Try other browser

Comment: Is this consistent across browsers ?